# Symfony, browser remembers view of page that requires to be logged in

Tags: php, symfony

When I close firefox when /twoj-panel/lista page is opened, and after whole day "restore previous session", that restricted page displays its last view. Why I'm not redirected to login page as usual. Below is my configuration.

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/twoj-panel, roles: ROLE_USER }

session:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    cookie_lifetime: 3600
    cookie_httponly: false
```

Comment: how do you keep session?

Comment: Well, you are restoring a session, so it's like browser was never closed. That should be the intended behaviour

Comment: Is there some way to delete this session to prevent firefox to restore it